# Display textbox for ItemStyle and MainContentQuery customization

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, content-query-web-part

I have the requirement to display a textbox on the content query webpart editor pane in which a user can type the path to a custom ItemStyle.xsl and MainContentQuery.xsl and the webpart will use the provided xsl's. How can i do this? I've seen tutorials about editing the .webpart file to point to a custom xsl, but this is not the case. I need to let the user fill in the path and make the content query web part use this path.